# функция def в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В программе уже есть запрос ввода двух чисел и передача их в функцию в качестве параметров. Твоя задача — определить функцию more_less. Если a > b, функция должна печатать строку "a больше b". Если a < b, функция должна печатать строку "a меньше b". Если a == b, функция должна печатать строку "a равно b".

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить.

```
a = int(input("Введите число 1:"))
b = int(input("Введите число 2:"))
def more_less(a, b):
    if a > b:
        print("a больше b")

more_less()
```

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Comment: Я бы смог сделать без функции def тупо с использованием условных операторов, но условие задачи таково, что нужно определить функцию more_less. А как это сделать, я вот хотел бы узнать

Comment: У вас же уже почти написано. Исправьте отступы, сделайте внутри функции полный условный оператор со всеми ветвями и передавайте в неё при вызове числа.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input("Введите число 1:"))
b = int(input("Введите число 2:"))

def more_less(a, b):
    if a > b:
        print("a больше b")
    elif a < b:
        print("a меньше b")
    else:
        print("a равно b")

more_less(a, b)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!Выручили

Answer (score 1):

Вы создали функцию, в которую при вызове нужно передать 2 аргумента: `a`, `b`.

```
more_less(a, b)
```